# Not able to get image using flutter library "image_picker"

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have updated the image_picker library in flutter to the latest version and when implementing the below code I am getting the error

CODE

```
File file = await ImagePicker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 675,
      maxWidth: 960,
    );
```

ERROR

```
error: Instance member 'getImage' can't be accessed using static access. 
error: A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
```

please guide me to resolve this

Comment: Can you add the complete code file as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message `ImagePicker.getImage()` return a `PickedFile`

You can convert it to `File` type like this:

```
PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  maxHeight: 675,
  maxWidth: 960,
);
            
File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
```

Comment: This works,
Instead of using **File file**, use **PickedFile pickedfile**,
Then after picking the image file assign the pickedfile path to a file object

Answer (score 0):

Intstall image picker and setup correctly

[Imagepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

**Initialize variables**

```
File _image;
final Imagepicker = ImagePicker();
```

**Button for opening bottom model**

```
 ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.red, // background
                onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                openImagePickerModal(context);},
              child: Text('Select Image'),
            ),
```

**To view selected Image**

```
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Image.file(
                _image,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )),
        ),
```

**Image Picker Model Bottom Sheet,For Select Images or Capture Image**

```
  void openImagePickerModal(BuildContext context) {
    final flatButtonColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 180.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Pick An Image',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: flatButtonColor,
                  child: Text(
                    'Use Camera',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Pickimage(context, ImageSource.camera);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: flatButtonColor,
                  child: Text(
                    'Use Gallery',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Pickimage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

**Function for Selecting Image from gallery or camera Image**

```
  Future Pickimage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
    if (source != null) {
      final pickedFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

      setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          _image = File(pickedFile.path);
       
        } else {
          print('No image selected.');
        }
      });
    } else {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with your above code  you have to change the package version

change the dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
 image_picker: ^0.6.0
```